# Syntax error: redirection unexpected　と出てきます。

Tags: ubuntu

GNU RadioをUbuntuにインストールして
 sudo wget http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio 
sudo chmod a+x ./build-gnuradio
sudo ./build-gnuradioを端末に入力すると
./build-gnuradio: 1: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open !DOCTYPE: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 1: ./build-gnuradio: HTML: not found
./build-gnuradio: 2: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open html: No such file
: not foundradio: 3: ./build-gnuradio: 
./build-gnuradio: 4: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open META: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 5: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open META: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 5: ./build-gnuradio: http-equiv=Content-Type: not found
./build-gnuradio: 6: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open META: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 6: ./build-gnuradio: http-equiv=Content-Style-Type: not found
./build-gnuradio: 7: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open title: No such file
: not foundradio: 8: ./build-gnuradio: NW�F�E���u�V�X�e���@���O�C�����
./build-gnuradio: 9: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open /title: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 10: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open body: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 11: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open center: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 12: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open img: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 13: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open h1: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 14: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open TABLE: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 15: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open TBODY: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 16: ./build-gnuradio: cannot open TR: No such file
./build-gnuradio: 17: ./build-gnuradio: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

最後にSyntax error: redirection unexpectedが出てきます。
文字化けもしていてファイルもありません。
GNU Radioのパッケージを入れたいのですがどうすればいいかわかりません
もしよろしければ教えていただきたいです。

Comment: そもそもダウンロードしたファイルの中身はシェルスクリプトですか？HTMLを無理やり実行しているように見えますが。。。。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから推察するに、`./build-gnuradio` ファイルが HTML ファイルになっているのではないでしょうか。`./build-gnuradio` ファイルの内容をご確認される事をお勧めします。

ちなみに、手元の Ubuntu 15.04 で `build-gnuradio` を実行すると以下の様に表示されます。

```
$ sudo ./build-gnuradio
Please run this script as an ordinary user
it will acquire root privileges as it needs them via "sudo".
```

Comment: ファイルの内容を確認する方法を教えて下さい

Comment: less コマンドで内容を表示して目視で確認するか、file コマンドを使います。「$ file build-gnuradio」とした場合、シェルスクリプトファイルであれば「build-gnuradio: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable」と表示されます。HTMLファイルであれば「HTML document, ASCII text」などと表示されることになります。

Comment: HTMLファイルでした。
このファイルを変更することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: wget コマンドでもう一度取得しなおすか、http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio のリンクを右クリックしてファイルに保存してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

GNU RadioはUbuntuのパッケージでいれればいいのだから`sudo apt-get install gnuradio`でOK。自分でビルドしなくていいです。